# How to optimise safecracker js & css

Tags: safecracker, javascript, css

I have a safecracker form that uses a number of third-party fieldtypes. The fieldtypes all require their own external javascript and css files. On what looks like a simple form the combined fields use approximately 30 asset files that add up to around 900 kb which isn't ideal.

Is there a good way to optimise this? My current thinking is to use the `include_jquery="no"` and `safecracker_head="no"` parameters and manually include the asset files and combine and minify using [Minimee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/minimee). However this isn't ideal as I'll need to reexamine all the assets files whenever an add-on is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution to this currently. The best route to optimization is what you're doing already. Carry-on!

Comment: Ha ha, thanks Derek. That's what I've done. I was able to reduce it to 4 external files and about 240kb once combined, minified and gzipped.